# Apache subversion LDAP group access per folder inside 1 repo

Tags: apache, svn, configuration, active-directory, ldap

I have been messing around with WANdisco subversion for a week already.
Here are the best links that helped:

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/06/apache_and_subversion_authentication_with_microsoft_active_directory/

http://blog.chadwestfall.com/2007/11/subversion-apache-active-directory.html

The problem is, all the information i find from internet is about Group per Repo access.

I need Group per repo folder access.
By that i mean i need to **limit access inside 1 repo**.

**Repo1\Folder1** -- Access to **everyone** authenticated in AD

**Repo1\Folder1\Subfolder** -- Access to certain AD group only - **Group1**

**Repo1\Folder2** -- Access to certain AD group only - **Group2**

**Repo1\Folder3** -- Access to multiple AD groups only - **Group1+Group2**

Is this possible and if yes, how to achieve it?

I got normal LDAP auth working but not with subfolders :(

Comment: There is no such product "WanDisco Subversion". Subversion is Apache Foundation product. PS: I recommend you to use VisualSVN Server if you want to authenticate against Active Directory.

Comment: Sorry for wrong information. Actually I am using a subversion pack that has LDAP authentication modules enabled from WANdisco.
More information from here:
http://www.wandisco.com/
As I said, normal authentication is working against AD.
Here is a workaround with python script:
http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/26?page=1
But I would still like to use subversion.conf solution

Comment: is this for pure open source subversion or uberSVN?  I found a similar suggestion on http://suggest.ubersvn.com/ and added the other.  See http://suggest.ubersvn.com/suggestions/110/populate-users-and-teams-from-ldap and http://suggest.ubersvn.com/suggestions/164/sub-directory-access-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work out of the box..
Paths in Subversion Repositories are not known to Apache
And Subversion gets only a username from Apache, so SVN  does not know about the LDAP Groups.

However you can write a small script importing the LDAP groups into your SVN-authz file and write the appropriate groups into the first lines of your authz file.

You can use a cron job to import changes on LDAP groups to authz file on a timely base.

Comment: ok thanks alot, i were not sure about this but you convinced me. Thanks ;)
I will try using the authz python script:
http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/26?page=1